# MySQL REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: mysql, sql, регулярные-выражения

В базе есть строки такого вида:

```
172653_preview_DSC04138_jpg62d70852f2d2944ac82e1f582523fd04_extjpg
```

Мне надо выделить первые цифры до _ : 172653 
Количество цифр может быть разным
Я написал такой запрос (рабочий)

```
update jino_pereezd.smf_aeva_files_scan
set file_name_id =
        left(
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_name, '[0-9]*\_'),
                length(REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_name, '[0-9]*\_')) - 1
            );
```

Вопрос: на мой вкус вышеприведенный запрос выглядит как то неизящно.
Можно ли тот же результат получить более простым способом?

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_name, '_', 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упростить можно использовав `replace`.

```
REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_name, '^(\d*)_'), '_', '')
```

Чтобы не попали другие цифры в строке, я привязался к началу строки `^`.

Выражение в скобках `(\d*)` означает подгруппу, обычно к ним можно обращаться по номеру. Но насколько я понял в mysql такой возможности не предусмотрено.